# SVG Server Side Calculations

Tags: svg, server-side

How to read a SVG file / inline SVG at server side and process it for SVG calculations. I need to calculate the SVG object colors, their areas. I have checked with 'SVG DOM reference'. How about if I want to use similar kind of APIs at server side. Is there any server-side programming available with rich API to read SVG data ?

Comment: batik + tomcat + some custom code to glue them together.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I am checking for batik if it works for me.

Comment: What about Node+jsdom?

Comment: Is there something available related to Java

Comment: if you are using java, go with batik+tomcat. the advantage of node+jsdom is that you can use the same code and libraries on your client and on your server ;-)

Comment: Stuck on in an area calculation for Polygon.
How to calculate the area of SVG path element using Java.
I am using Batik for SVG.